# Calculate Field calculates once

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, field-calculator, python-parser

Why did Calc Field work the first time I wrote the following code, but not when I re-ran it with an additional criteria? I figured out the code I needed to classify all fields in a new attribute column. Conditionally, if a feature is already defined as one of several road types in a separate column, e.g. interstate, ramp, frontage, then classify that feature as restricted to pedestrians in a new column. Eventually, I was able to write something that satisfied python, and I ran it and it worked. Then I realized I wanted to add another condition, however, I've added a new line to run and nothing is happening. So my first successful code worked once, and I haven't gotten it to work with an extra edit to meet an extra condition.

```
def Reclass (ROADCAT_DS):
   if ROADCAT_DS == 'Frontage road': return 'Y'
   elif ROADCAT_DS == 'Interstate highway': return 'Y'
   elif ROADCAT_DS == 'Interstate ramp': return 'Y'
   elif ROADCAT_DS == 'Major road ramp': return 'Y'
   elif ROADCAT_DS == 'State route ramp': return 'Y'
   elif ROADCAT_DS == 'State route': return 'Y'
   else: return 'N'
```

[image]

Comment: You could compress that to a single ternary `'Y' if !ROADCAT_DS! in ['Frontage road',...,'State route'] else 'N'`

Comment: Thanks @Vince, but that didn't work, syntax error
File "<string>", line 4
    'Y' if ROADCAT_DS in ['Frontage road','Interstate highway','Major road ramp','State route', 'State route ramp'] 
                                                                                                                    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
.

Comment: The `!` variable wrappers were left off, and there isn't an `else`

Comment: File "<string>", line 4
    'Y' if !ROADCAT_DS! in ['Frontage road',...,'State route'] else 'N'
           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: The `...` has to contain the other terms, as in the previous attempt

Comment: 'Y' if !ROADCAT_DS! in ['Frontage road','Interstate highway','Interstate ramp','State route','State route ramp','Major road ramp'] else 'N'
           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Works fine in my Pro 3.2.  You did place it all on the line above the Code Block, right.

Comment: no, i put it in the code block

Comment: The Code Block must be valid Python, which the `!ROADCAT_DS!` isn't. You could make a two-line function, prefixing the 'Y' with `return`, but then you need to name the variable correctly.

Comment: What you're describing sounds like my original code: there are no ! in the code block, Ys are prefixed with return

Comment: One last time: That whole function could be replaced with a single Python3 expression line. If you insist on defining a function, then it could be two lines of code (the `def` and the ternary `return`). Python code should *always* use four spaces for indentation, as per the [PEP8](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/) style guide.

Comment: Ok, thanks you. I'm trying to solve a practical issue, and I have a limited python vocabulary, and I don't know what a 'function' is. I'm not insisting on anything, I'm just trying to write a logical code that meets python syntax criteria. I have no idea whether def is necessary. What I wrote is the only thing that has worked thus far, and only once.

Comment: You need to [Edit] the Question to focus on the "only once" part, since it makes no sense whatsoever. You only need to wade a few chapters deep into a Python book to have the skill necessary to write Calculate Field expressions, but without those chapters, you'll never understand the Answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150843/discussion-between-ryan-stephenson-and-vince).

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150844/discussion-on-question-by-ryan-stephenson-calculate-field-calculates-once); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Comment: This Edit doesn't clarify the problem. You need to provide the working *and* non-working code. How you added that "additional criteria" is critical, as well as the error or other indication of problem.